# In Swift what is purpose of using UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier. how below mentioned code will execute

Tags: ios, swift

```
 self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        print("animateRightToLeft: went here")
        if let indentifier = self.backgroundTaskIdentifier {
            print("animateRightToLeft: stop here")
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(indentifier)
       }
  })
```

My App auto killed after some time if App goes background.
   Can some one advice is it because of the above code?

Comment: What kind of operation are you trying to request additional background time for? What do you intend "animateRightToLeft" to be? (Basically, why do you want to run in the background?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be much easier to help you if you explain what you are trying to do? The code you provided will only allow your app to execute code in background for limited amount of time (currently 180 seconds on my iPhone 7).

Detailed:
Once you call beginBackgroundTask, you are given a timer which starts running after your app goes to background. While that timer is running, your app will be executing code even in background. When this timer runs out, or you call endBackgroundTask, your code will stop executing in background. Also if that timer runs out before you called endBackgroundTask, your expiration handler will be called and you should call endBackgroundTask there.

Please note that the code you wrote in the expirationHandler will be called only if you don't call endBackgroundTask before timer runs out.

You can use this code to test how it all behaves, e.g. if you run it as is, app will print backgroundTimeRemaining in the console even when in background. If you comment beginBackgroundTask your app will not print anything after it goes to background.

```
private var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
var timer: Timer?


@IBAction func buttontapped(_ sender: Any)
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block:
    {
        (timer) in

        NSLog("$$$$$ Time remaining: \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining)")
    })

    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:
    {
        NSLog("$$$$$ Timer expired: Your app will not be executing code in background anymore.")

        if let indentifier = self.backgroundTaskIdentifier
        {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(indentifier)
        }
    })

    NSLog("$$$$$ start")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 30)
    {
        NSLog("$$$$$ end")
        if let indentifier = self.backgroundTaskIdentifier
        {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(indentifier)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: few doubts:- By default if i have not given any background task and added timer in view controller, how long it will run? How to have a session time handler for App for 15 min ? As per your code dispatch async queue you have added 30 min to kill background task. will it run for 30 mins? Can i conclude my understanding if i am not giving any background task the timer will stop as per OS handling, for example that you have mentioned 180 sec for iphone 7.

Comment: If you don't give it background task, app will stop executing code (timer will stop running) immediately after it goes into background. 

In my code above, asyncAfter will execute block after 30 seconds, not minutes. If I have put 30 minutes there, then block would never be executed because app will give me only 180 seconds, so expiration handler would be called before my block.

I suggest you paste my code in your project and play with it, see how it works when you e.g. comment beginBackgroundTask or change value of asyncAfter.

Comment: Your example was much clear. But i tried one more thing. I tapped 4 , 5 times in the button, that many time background task created and because of this latest identifier will be passed to the end background task. My expectation was App will terminate but it was not.

Comment: Yes I expected app to crash too but it didn't, don't know why. App should crash after timer runs out because you ended only last background task. If you have multiple tasks, you should save their identifiers in array/dictionary and call endBackgroundTask on each.

Comment: May be is it because of small source code and that to in simulator.

Answer (score 2):

From Docs `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)`

> This method requests additional background execution time for your app. Call this method when leaving a task unfinished might be detrimental to your app’s user experience. For example, call this method before writing data to a file to prevent the system from suspending your app while the operation is in progress. Do not use this method simply to keep your app running after it moves to the background.
>
> Each call to this method must be balanced by a matching call to the endBackgroundTask(_:) method.

My App auto killed after some time if App goes background , is it because of the above code?

> no it isn't the above snippet only asks for additional time until task is finished , your app will be terminated anyway

Comment: "Each call to this method must be balanced by a matching call to the endBackgroundTask(_:) method."
what will happen if it not balanced.?
i have to study the syntax though i am asking aa doubt. is my code is balanced?

Comment: Apple states:"Failure to end the task explicitly will result in the termination of the app". But in my testing app is not terminated.